# When is an NSFetchedResultsController updated?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using an `NSFetchedResultsController` that uses a predicate to fetch some managed objects. I have always assumed that the `NSFetchedResultsController` is updated when the objects change, i.e. if I have a predicate `"box == 3"` and `box` is changed to `2`, it won't be fetched.

However, even though I changed the objects and saved the managed object context, I can still access the object through my FRC. Even when deleting the cache, this is still possible.

Is this the correct behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further testing I think it is save to assume that the `FRC` is not updated without me doing something. I only call `-performFetch:` once and I did not implement the delegate. According to the docs the `FRC` *seems* to only then register for change notifications:

> If you set a delegate for a fetched results controller, the controller
>   registers to receive change notifications from its managed object
>   context.

Answer (score 2):

Did you set a delegate for the NSFetchedResultsController?  When changes occur in the managed object context, the NSFetchedResultsController's delegate is the one that is notified of the changes.  Please see the following:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to e.g. update your table is just to set the FRC to `nil` and reload. That tends to take care of all the updating problems and is also quite efficient. The FRC will lazily recreate itself and populate your table.

```
self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: I am not actually using it for a table view in this example.